# Restore session in MSFT Edge is gone

Tags: session, tabs, microsoft-edge, restore

I updated Windows 10 a couple of days ago, and after the restart, all my tabs in Edge were gone.  The 2 windows with 142 tabs were not showing in the "Recently closed" section of the History sub-menu.  The only help I could find online was this question on StackOverflow - [How to restore session in Microsoft Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117660/how-to-restore-session-in-microsoft-edge) - but the Recovery/Active folder with the 142 files (presumably the lost tabs) there would not update with new files after opening and closing Edge multiple times.  Every time the 142 files would still be there.  Still, I copied that folder and stored it in a safe place.

I guess the Windows update somehow changed the settings of Edge and how the session/restore tabs thing works in the settings.  I can go through history, but I am not sure which ones would be the ones that were gone.  It would take too much time.  Please advise me on how to restore my lost tabs.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it looks like you are using the **MS Edge Chromium** browser. As **Recently closed** option is available in the **MS Edge Chromium** browser.

[image]

You are referring to the old thread that is about the MS Edge legacy browser. I think it will not help to fix the issue for the **MS Edge Chromium** browser.

The new **MS Edge Chromium** browser is not dependent on Windows updates. So installing the latest Windows updates will not change anything in the **MS Edge Chromium** browser.

I suggest you go to `Settings and more(Alt + F)-> History-> Click the last option that shows N number of tabs`.

[image]

You can also try to check the following points may help to narrow down the issue.

1. Check and make sure that you are not using any other profile. You need to use the same profile in which these tabs you had opened.
2. You will not be able to restore the tabs that are opened in private mode.
3. Try to press `CTRL + SHIFT + T` key repeatedly. See whether it is opening the previous tabs or not.
4. I want to confirm with you, does your **recently closed** tabs section shows 142 entries of sites? If not, it can be possible that the data got cleared. Can you please inform me which location you are referring to in the file explorer to check those history files for the Edge browser? It can be possible that you are referring to the location for the Edge legacy browser.

Let us know about your test results.